# Session management via pure CGI

Tags: c, cgi, session

I'm currently in the process of writing a little blog / generic posting system using CGI in C as a hobby project and am now in the need of a session management system to authentificate authorized users for posting, editing and similar operations over **multiple CGI programs**

From working with PHP years ago I remember using the superglobal variable `$_SESSION` and some session intializing functions. *Obviously* this is not going to work this way when dealing with pure CGI, so I'm in a tricky situation here.

A bit of thinking showed that there's many different ways to do such a thing...

1. Saving the IP address and attributes inside a file where I can see if a particular IP is authorized
2. Same as #1 but using an SQLite database (my engine already runs on SQLite so there would be no additional overhead)
3. Something with cookies maybe?

Instead of going all in and regret is later... what do **you** good people think? What's the most efficient (and most importantly) and the maintainable method?

Please note that I do *not* want to get a third party libary to do all the complicated things for me! I started this project to build something completely by myself (if you ignore SQLite here) and I don't want to hide the hard parts, even if it makes everything so much simpler. I could have just used Python if I didn't want to torture myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie based session management is the way to go. You cannot merely use an IP address not even IP address + browser combination because that will fail when people are using proxy or are behind NAT.

Just send the browser a hash in a cookie, then validate the hash against your record for the user, if it matches, you can then access the data for that user's session.

Consider adding an expiry mechanism for the hash. There is a trade off between security and ease of use, because the longer the same hash is valid for the user, the longer the user is vulnerable to a cookie stealing attack.

Expiry mechanisms will also enable you to delete stale session data from your database (or file, if you would so choose.)

Comment: Thanks, I only need to decide where to save my sessions now.. probably inside my sqlite db, just for consistency.